# Referring to Users in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

I'm saving a list of values for each user on my Django app, taken from a daily poll. I can't get the 'User' field `responder` to save properly as it always opts for the default value 'Null'. Instead of a list of values for each user, I am getting a single list in the database for all the users combined.

Here is my model:

```
class Repondez(Model):
    score_list = JSONField()
    responder = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.score_list
```

Here is views.py:

```
r = Repondez()
r.score_list = []
global list_length

def home(request):
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'rating/home.html', context)

@login_required
def add(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_option = (request.POST['rating'])
        list_length = len(r.score_list)
        if selected_option == 'option1':
            r.score_list.append(1)
        elif selected_option == 'option2':
            r.score_list.append(2)
        elif selected_option == 'option3':
            r.score_list.append(3)
        elif selected_option == 'option4':
            r.score_list.append(4)
        elif selected_option == 'option5':
            r.score_list.append(5)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(400, 'Invalid form')

        r.save()

        return redirect(add)

    context = {
        'r' : r,
    }
    return render(request, 'rating/add.html', context)
```

I have tried to avoid having a default value for `responder` but am always asked for one during `migrate`. I tried a ForeignKey and ManytoManyField for the 'User' relationship as well but in each case I am getting a single, combined list for all users. How can I save the `responder` field properly so each list is saved for their respective user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your add view you need to set the responder field for the instance:

```
r.responder = request.user
r.save()
```

Ok to solve the list issue you are having I would change the model to use a foreign key to the user instead of onetoone field

```
class Respondez(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = (‘day’,)
    responder = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
        related_name=‘scores’)
    score = models.IntegerField()
    day = models.DateField(auto_add_now=True)
```

Then access the scores from the user instance like so:

```
request.user.scores.all()
```

You can also access the score list using values_list:

```
request.user.scores.all().values_list(‘score’, flat=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that, but I still get a single list of values in my database. The responder field is updating with the name of the most recent user to save. 

Do you know how I can get the list to split out for each user?

Comment: I believe it’s because your instantiating the r globally try putting that in your view as well

Comment: I think I'm getting really close. I put r locally and changed the model so that it is saving individual values instead of a list of values. This is working and it is saving values for each user separately.

The issue is still with saving lists. I made a separate model for lists and one of two things happen:
- I instantiate the list model globally and get a single list for all users OR
- Instantiate locally - this results in a NEW list being saved for each user with each response, instead of just a single list for each user. I'm not sure why as the model uses a OneToOneField with user.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve with the list? Maybe I can help if I understand what you’re trying to do?

Comment: The project is a daily mood tracker. Each day users select a rating from 1-5. These values (1-5) are going into a list which will be plotted over time. 

I chose a list because I'm not sure how else I could plot an increasing set of values over time.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you!! The only changes were using a value_list that looked like this: request.user.scores.values_list('score', flat=True). You've saved me tons of time stuck on JSONField

Comment: Glad I could help